# How get autoID of new object after calling push() in firebase?

Tags: firebase

It's simple. I have an object called `obj` and the reference called `ref`
when I do:

```
ref.push(obj, function(err){});
```

or

```
ref.push().set(obj, function(err){});
```

how do I get the auto generated ID of the recently saved object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `push` function returns a reference to the newly created object.

```
var newRef = ref.push();
console.log(newRef.name());
newRef.set(obj, function(err) {});
```

Note that in the above snippet no data is sent to the server until the call to `set`. The `push()` method is pure client-side, as long as you don't pass any data into it.

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/push.html

Comment: "The unique name generated by push() is prefixed with a client-generated timestamp so that the resulting list will be chronologically-sorted." Does this mean the two clients with different device time will produce chronologically inconsistent list?

Comment: If you care about ordering across clients, you should probably use `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`. Either set it as the priority, or include it as a value in your object. See: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/servervalue/timestamp.html . One thing to keep in mind though: when using multiple clients, these timestamps are likely to be non-unique. So they're great for ordering data, but not to use as an ID.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That's not *quite* right. `push()` is an alias for generating a new id and invoking `set()` on it. Invoking `push()` without an argument is purely client-side, but passing in data, such as `push(myObj)` will call `set()` under the hood and write to the server. Can you update your answer?

Comment: Modified. I did know that `push(obj)` is just a shorthand for `push().set(obj)`, but it might indeed not have come across clearly enough in my answer.